# kafka could not find or load main class

Tags: apache-kafka

I just want to use kafka on my Ubuntu 16.04.

But when I run:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

I got the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class :.usr.java.jdk1.8.0_151.lib:.usr.java.jdk1.8.0_151.jre.lib:.usr.java.jdk1.8.0_151.lib:.usr.java.jdk1.8.0_151.jre.lib:.usr.scala-2.11.12.lib:.usr.kafka.kafka_2.11-0.11.0.2.libs:.usr.java.jdk1.8.0_151.lib:.usr.java.jdk1.8.0_151.jre.lib:.usr.scala-2.11.12.lib:.usr.java.jdk1.8.0_151.lib:...
```

and so on.

Here is my `/etc/profile`:

```
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/scala-2.11.12

export KAFKA_HOME=/usr/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.2

export ZOOKEEPER_HOME=/usr/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.5

export M2_HOME=/usr/java/apache-maven-3.5.2

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_151

export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre

export CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JRE_HOME/lib:$SCALA_HOME/lib:$KAFKA_HOME/libs

export PATH=$PATH:$ZOOKEEPER_HOME/bin:$M2_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$SCALA_HOME/bin:$KAFKA_HOME/bin
```

What could be the problem?